# Is there any way to print a database content in a pretty syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple database in ruby on rail and i want to know if there is a way to display properly the result of a request in ruby.

For example in a base which is like this : User(id, name, email)
whith a content like that :

(1, jack, j@j.com);(2, jhon, jo@jo.com); (3, janet, j@j.com)

I do `rails console` then
`User.where(email: "j@j.com")`

It return two line but it's not correctly formated to be lisible. Do you know some command in order to well format the output when you have multiple line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I like to use is the `y` helper, which will convert the given object to YAML format. This solution does not require any additional Gems.

```
irb> y User.last
--- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  id: 26
  first_name: Arthur
  last_name: Dent
  created_at: 2015-05-21 14:38:09.569623000 Z
```

You can also use the [awesome_print Gem](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print), which will give you the `ap` helper:

```
irb> ap User.last
#<User:0x007fea6aa121e0> {
            :id => 26,
    :first_name => "Arthur",
     :last_name => "Dent"
    :created_at => Thu, 21 May 2015 14:38:09 UTC +00:00
}
```